# prestashop distribution modules

Tags: module, prestashop

I'm searching, but I can't find. I need a plugin/module to prestashop which generate link for my partner. When customer click link on partner's page and access to shop throw that link and do shopping, I know that this customer come to me from this partner.

Does anyone know how this plugin / module called?

Comment: could you please explain your requirement in detail, please share what you have tried, the code that you are stuck now ?

Comment: Let me explain.
1. The module generates a link to the partner.
2. Partner shall place a link on your site.
3. The customer enters the partner site.
4. The customer sees and clicks a link in it.
5. The link is transferred to the page of my store, and if you do shopping, somewhere it points out that it is from this partner so that he can be, for example, assign discounts.